# Scroll recyclerview to new position after Room update

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I have a `recyclerView` showing a list of users from a Room database.

Dao

```
    @Query("SELECT * from users_table ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC")
    LiveData<List<User_Entity>> getAllUsers();
```

activity

```
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.traininglistview);
    usersViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UsersViewModel.class);

    usersViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<User_Entity>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<User_Entity> user_entities) {
            mUsers = user_entities;
            mAdapter.setUsers(user_entities);
        }
    });

    mAdapter = new UsersAdapter(context, usersViewModel);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    ...
```

The list of users is ordered by the user name.

When I click a user item, a new Activity is launched to allow me to edit user values.

If I change the user name, because my query is ordered by name, the new user recyclerView position is changed.

When returning from user values edit, how can I scroll my recyclerView to show the just edited user? Or, how can I found the new user list position to use `mLayoutManager.scrollToPosition`?

Comment: You need to somehow save the ID which is going update because it will remain the same . So after updation when `onChanged` called loop through the list and find the position for this particular ID .

Comment: @ADM thanks for replying. Yes, I thought about this solution, however, when you have a lot of users, a loop seems not to be very efficient. I expected something like a `locate` function that can return the record number...

Comment: The Locate function will have the same logic since we do not know the index after updation. We need to find out index Somehow .  I think this can easier with `DiffUtils` . Have a look at `DiffUtils`..

Comment: Why not do the search in the updated ArrayList using `indexOf()`? It will return item's position which you can use in `scrollToPosition()`

Comment: @elbertrivas Thanks, but with a Room query, this will always return -1.

Comment: @ADM +1 Thanks, finally seems that a loop is enough.